# Running my JSP myEclipse page gives a blank page

Tags: java, myeclipse

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to create a project in myEclipse latest version and I'm using the following code:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*,java.sql.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="<%=basePath%>">
     <title>My JSP 'blockmails.jsp' starting page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">    
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
    <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    -->
 </head>
   <%
          try
    {
        String flag="false";
        String ctr="false";
        String mailto=session.getAttribute("mailto").toString();
        String sub=session.getAttribute("subject").toString();
        String mess=session.getAttribute("message").toString();
        String user=request.getParameter("user");
        System.out.println(mailto+" "+sub+" "+mess+" "+user);
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","email","email");
        Statement pst=con.createStatement();
        Statement pst1=con.createStatement();
        //System.out.println("pst1:"+pst1);
        //System.out.println("pst2:"+pst2);
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        Statement srs=con.createStatement();
        Statement st3=con.createStatement();
        //out.println("connection estblished");
        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery("select * from Encryptedwords");
       ResultSet rs2=st3.executeQuery("select * from swords");
      while(rs.next()&& rs2.next())
        {
            String query="select * from MAILS where subject like '%"+rs.getString(1)+"%' or subject like '%"+rs2.getString(1)+"%' or message like '%"+rs.getString(1)+"%' or message like '%"+rs2.getString(1)+"%' and mailfrom='"+user+"'";
            
            ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSet rsr1=srs.executeQuery("select * from MAILS where subject like '%"+rs.getString(2)+"%' or message like '%"+rs.getString(2)+"%' and mailfrom='"+user+"'");
            if(rs1.next()||rsr1.next())
            {
                flag="true";
                break;
            }
            else
                flag="false";   
        }
        if(flag.equals("true"))
        {
            //out.println("suspicious");
            String to=user;
            String mailfrom="GNITS@suspicious mail.com";
            String subject="mail-daemon";
            String message="The mail you had sent consists of suspicious information";
            PreparedStatement pst2=con.prepareStatement("insert into inbox values(?,?,?,?)");
            pst2.setString(1,to);
            pst2.setString(2,mailfrom);
            pst2.setString(3,subject);
            pst2.setString(4,message);
            int d=pst2.executeUpdate();
        PreparedStatement pst3=con.prepareStatement("insert into blocklist values(?,?,?,?)");
            pst3.setString(1,mailto);
            pst3.setString(2,user);
            pst3.setString(3,sub);
            pst3.setString(4,mess);
            int r=pst3.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("r is:"+d);
            if(d>0)
            {
                Statement st2=con.createStatement();
                st2.executeUpdate("delete from mails");
                response.sendRedirect("inbox.jsp?user="+to);
            }
            
        }
        else
        {   
            
            Statement pss=con.createStatement();
     ResultSet sr=pss.executeQuery("select * from alertwords");
        //out.println(sr);
         while(sr.next())
        {
            Statement ss=con.createStatement();
            String query2="select * from MAILS where subject like '%"+sr.getString(1)+"%' or message like '%"+sr.getString(1)+"%' and mailfrom='"+user+"'";
            out.println("hello");
            out.println("query:"+query2);
            ResultSet sr1=ss.executeQuery(query2);
            out.println(sr1);
            if(sr1.next())
            {
                ctr="true";
                break;
            }
            else
                ctr="false";
               }
        if(ctr.equals("true"))
            {
            /*System.out.println("suspicious");
            String to=user;
            String mailfrom="krest@gmail.com";
            String subject="mail-daemon";
            String message="The mail you had sent consists of suspicious information";*/
            /*PreparedStatement pss1=con.prepareStatement("insert into inbox values(?,?,?,?)");
            pss1.setString(1,mailto);
            pss1.setString(2,mailfrom);
            pss1.setString(3,subject);
            pss1.setString(4,message);
            int d1=pss1.executeUpdate();*/
    PreparedStatement pss4=con.prepareStatement("insert into inbox values(?,?,?,?)");
            pss4.setString(1,mailto);
            pss4.setString(2,user);
            pss4.setString(3,sub);
            pss4.setString(4,mess);
            int rk=pss4.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("r is:"+rk);
PreparedStatement pss3=con.prepareStatement("insert into alertlist values(?,?,?,?)");
            pss3.setString(1,mailto);
            pss3.setString(2,user);
            pss3.setString(3,sub);
            pss3.setString(4,mess);
            int r1=pss3.executeUpdate();
            /*System.out.println("r is:"+d1);
            if(d1>0)
            {
                Statement st3=con.createStatement();
                st3.executeUpdate("delete from mails");
                response.sendRedirect("inbox.jsp?user="+to);
            }*/
        }
        else
            System.out.println("not suspicious");
      PreparedStatement pss2=con.prepareStatement("insert into inbox values(?,?,?,?)");
            pss2.setString(1,mailto);
            pss2.setString(2,user);
            pss2.setString(3,sub);
            pss2.setString(4,mess);
            int r=pss2.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("r is:"+r);
            if(r>0)
            {
                Statement st4=con.createStatement();
                st4.executeUpdate("delete from mails");
                response.sendRedirect("user.jsp?user="+user);
                //out.println("mail sent successfully");
            }
        }
}
    catch(Exception e){}
%>
</html>
```

I'm trying to create a JSP page. But the problem is, when I try to run the code, it gives a blank page. No errors or anything. Just blank. I'm very confused and I have been at this for weeks now, with no progress at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a large chunk of code to help debug. Any errors in the server console when you deploy the application and/or open the page? Checked the browser's console output too? Have you tried stripping down this code to something very simple (or the default JSP page that MyEclipse creates) to see if that produces output? Once that does, you can slowly add bits of code back in to see at what point it starts to fail.

Comment: To better debug this piece of code, why don't you separate the JSP code (presentation logic) from the Java code (app logic)? That is, all Java code go to a .java file and all JSP code go to a .jsp file. MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern.